# How does Azure's EventData.PartitionKey decide which partition to write to?

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to implement an Event Hub in Azure. I have managed to create a Producer which publishes messages to the Event Hub, as well as a Consumer which reads them off. My Event Hub is divided up into 16 partitions. On the consumer side, I loop through each of these as follows:

```
var eventHub = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString()).GetEventHub("de-analytics-events");

foreach (var partitionId in eventHub.PartitionIds)
{
     subscriberGroup.RegisterProcessor<EventProcessor>(new Lease
     {
         PartitionId = partitionId
     }, new EventProcessorCheckpointManager());

     Console.WriteLine("Processing: " + partitionId);
}
```

Looking at these values in a debugger shows that the `eventHub.PartitionIds` range from "0" to "15" in the case of 16 partitions.

However, on the producer side, all I was allowed to specify was my `EventData.PartitionKey`, which is a string, but which does not directly correspond to the strings on the consumer side. E.g. if I specified a PartitionKey = "7", it did not necessarily write to partition "7".

Reading up shows that some sort of hashing is involved, but I don't particularly want to guess randomly at 16 strings that hash to the numbers 0-15. So I'm wondering how I can define which partition is published to?

For added reference, [this](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/getting-acquainted-with-azure-service-bus-event-hubs/) is the tutorial I followed to get my simplest case working.

Comment: I wrote a very primitive clone of the the whole partition processing similar to Event Hubs and Kafka its called NPartition. Its on github. https://github.com/jeremychild/NPartition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct, a hash is used to translate the partition key to a given partition.  The question I have then, is as long as the hash algorithm distributes events evenly and consistently, why should you really care which partition the message is assigned to?

Yes, you could argue that you want to know so you know who the receiver will be. But the reality is that tight coupling like this makes the solution inherently fragile. You're betting off letting the service do what it needs to do to keep traffic healthy and realize that once you get a message using a given partition key, you're very likely to always get messages using that key.

The bigger challenge is to ensure that the partition key strategy you use is one that will help ensure a fairly even distribution of events across the partitions (aka don't give 10,000 devices all the same partition key).

Comment: Hmm it was more of a distribution of concerns approach. Perhaps I don't fully understand the event hub quite yet (not surprisingly, the documentation is still pretty sparse). I get that for cases where the number of devices writing to partitions is large, the hashing evenly distributes load. But I only expect maybe 2 or 3 times the number of partitions publishers. I guess it's robust enough to handle more and more publishers, I was just wondering if there was a way to manually handle the process since I'm only dealing with a small number of publishers

Comment: As an added note, the above approach I used is very manual and not particularly robust...the `EventProcessorHost` mentioned in the tutorial within my question is a better approach to listening on all partitions

Comment: If you're talking such a limited number of publishers, might I suggest looking at a partitioned queue? By enabling partitioning, you'll increase the throughput by up to 16x over a single queue if you're processing the puts and gets properly (aka async calls are essential)

Comment: The `partitionKey` is used to sequence the events. In a distributed system related events can come out of order, and in _some_ cases it is important to sequence them in the order they're processed. Using `partitionKey` will achieve that. The assumption is the hashing algorithm will take care of avoiding hot partitions as long as the `partitionKey` has high cardinality (just like cosmos db does). Using timestamp for order is fragile due to clockskew https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#mapping-of-events-to-partitions

Answer (score 9):

Specifying PartitionKey will ensure that all the events that have the same key are sent to the same partition and there is order maintained for these events within the partition.

Do you have such requirement for your data on the processing side?

If you don't have such requirement then the recommendation is to "not set the PartitionKey". That ways Event hub broker will distribute the events amongst the partitions uniformly.

If you do have the order guarantee requirements for your data within a PartitionKey and you have a small number of publishers then there is manual way of handling the partitions and distributing load using the Partitioned Sender.
Refer to this link on how to use the Partitioned Sender.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.createpartitionedsender.aspx