# Azure eventhub multiple partition key points to same partition

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We are working on a multi-tenant application where eventhub will be shared among different tenants. We will distribute the partitions among our tenants. Every tenant will sending message on different partition. We want to authenticate tenant on partition level. As describe on Microsoft site, we defined partition key based on tenant Id. But the problem is more then one partition key is sending message on same partition. Which should not be the case. Ideally every partition key should be mapped to different partition.

```
        var serviceNamespace = "namespace name here";
        var hubName = "hub name here";
        var deviceName = "device name here";
        var sasToken = "SAS TOKEN HERE";

        Mymessage subGroup1 = CreateMessage();

        var factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, ""), new MessagingFactorySettings
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(sasToken),
            TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
        });
        var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(String.Format("{0}/publishers/{1}", hubName, deviceName));

        var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subGroup1)));
        data.PartitionKey = "jeep";

        client.Send(data);
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply the ~infinite space of possible string partition keys is mapped to the very finite space of partitions within the Event Hub. Unless you asked Microsoft for more you have at most 32 partitions within your EventHub. The partition key gets hashed and then the hash space is divided amongst the space of partitions. This provides the guarantee in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn836025.aspx)

> Event Hubs ensures that any and all events sharing the same partition key value are delivered in order, and to the same partition. Importantly, if partition keys are used with publisher policies, described in the next section, then the identity of the publisher and the value of the partition key must match.

What is not guaranteed, and could not be guaranteed in this sort of system with good performance, is that each partition key goes to a different partition. Some of this is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876671/how-does-azures-eventdata-partitionkey-decide-which-partition-to-write-to). With publisher policies you also know that

> When using publisher policies, the PartitionKey value is set to the publisher name. In order to work properly, these values must match.

which means all events from a single publisher go to a single partition. Personally, I don't think that's always a good thing because you end up with a hard cap of one throughput unit (less if you're unlucky in hashing) per publisher.

If you need separation of each customer's data in different partitions with this being enforced by the credentials given to the customer to talk directly to the EventHub, I think your only option may be to use multiple EventHubs. I *believe* (in the sense I haven't examined our bill yet) that EventHubs within the same Service Bus share throughput units.

However, if you just need your consumer to be able to tell what publisher/customer it came from, then I believe you can just use [EventData.PartitionKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.partitionkey.aspx) which is guaranteed to be the publisher name as documented above.

Comment: event hub is same namespace do share the throughput units. But problem with different eventhub is that we will not be able to share consumers role. Some of our tenants will be sending data at very slower rate. Having different consumer role for them does not make any sense. And then, we will have to create two instances of consumer (worker role machine) to achieve high availability. We want to create a SaaS application where resources can be shared among tenants so that it costs lesser to them.

Comment: In that case I believe your option is that in the last sentence. That is relying on the PartitionKey to separate out the data from different clients. You're still stuck with the scalability cap though.

Comment: Can't I do reverse engineering. I can check what string gets mapped to partition1 and then check for parition2 and so on. We can then generate SAS keys using these string. We can distribute these strings to our tenants. This way we can make sure that 'xxxx' string is mapped to 'partition_x' and 'sas_key_x' can only be used to pass data to partition_x. I know this is not clean but can serve the purpose :)

Comment: cacsar, I will calculate no_of_partition required based on msg/sec.we are expecting from one tenant and will provide equal number of partition key to him. He will distribute these keys to its devices. Tomorrow if any tenant grows and wants to send more message, i will provide him more partition keys.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it would work out too well for you. You would end up with a set maximum number of customers on your event hub when you created it. This *might* be fine for you given your business needs. Remember that you can have one process consume from multiple event hubs. Why do you need them to be different partitions? To have a guaranteed per customer scalability?

Comment: Then yes guessing the hashes can work if you're in a position to do manual key assignment as things grow.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. How can one process consume from different event hub? EventProcessorHost works on single event hub with multiple partitions. And it automatically balance the load when you add another worker role (with EventhProcessorHost). I don't know if I can get this behavior with multiple event hub. Please let me know if it is feasible.

Comment: Just have one process register two EventProcessorHosts each pointing at a different EventHub.

Comment: Thanks cacsar. This was really helpful. I never thought having different eventhubs. I don't know which one is more clean. 500 EventProcessorHost or 1 EventHost with 500 partitions? How will we register 500 EventProcessorHost on consumer? Will evaluate though. But on consumer side, it looks like 1 eventhub with 500 seems more feasible.

Comment: @Pragmatic : a point worth noting about the hashing logic you were planning to use - Microsoft didn't give out the algo. for hashing so that they will change it! So, although you reverse-engineer and find out the PartitionKey to PartitionId Mapping - it is bound to change.