# Authorization in Event Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am using SAS token authentication along with device-ID (or publisher-Id) in my event Hub publisher code. But i see that it is possible to send an event to any partition ID by using "CreatePartitionedSender" client even though I have authenticated using a device-ID. Whereas I do not want two different device-Ids publishing events in same partition. Is it possible that we can add some custom "**authorization**" code along with the SAS authentication to allow limited  partition access to any device.

The idea behind adding authorization to device and partition-Id combination was to accommodate single event-hub for multiple tenants. Please advise if I am missing anything.

Please see below the code snippet for publisher:

```
        var publisherId = "1d8480fd-d1e7-48f9-9aa3-6e627bd38bae"; 
        string token = SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.GetPublisherSharedAccessSignature(
               new Uri("sb://anyhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"),
               eventHubName, publisherId, "send",
               sasKey,
               new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

           var factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "anyhub-ns", ""), new MessagingFactorySettings
           {
               TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(token),
               TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
           });

           var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(String.Format("{0}/publishers/{1}", eventHubName, publisherId));

           var message = "Event  message for publisher: " + publisherId;

           Console.WriteLine(message);

           var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

           await client.SendAsync(eventData);

           await client.CreatePartitionedSender("5").SendAsync(eventData);

           await client.CreatePartitionedSender("6").SendAsync(eventData);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292330/azure-eventhub-multiple-partition-key-points-to-same-partition for the part where partitions are going to be shared unless you jump through hoops. Not having used SAS tokens myself, I'm only going to guess, but using the restricted publisher URI (<my namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<event hub name>/publishers/<my publisher name>) in the SAS URI may provide the restriction you need. Never used it but the docs imply that to me.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your example code that you have

```
var connStr = ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder.CreateUsingSharedAde...
```

and then have

```
CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString
```

This suggests that you may have used a Connection String containing the send key you used to generate the token rather than the limited access token. In my own tests I did not manage to connect to an EventHub using the EventHubClient, which makes an AMQP connection, with a publisher specific token. This doesn't mean it's not supported just that I got errors that made sense, and the ability to do so doesn't *appear* to be documented.

What is documented and has an [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Event-Hub-99ce67ab) is making the publisher specific tokens and sending events to the EventHub using the HTTP interface. If you examine the SAS token generated you can see that the token grants access to

```
[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/[eventhubname]/publishers/[publisherId]
```

This is consistent with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn789974.aspx) on the security model, and the general discussion of publisher policies in the [overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn836025.aspx). I would expect the guarantee on publisherId -> PartitionKey to hold with this interface. Thus each publisherId would have its events end up in a consistent partition.

This may be less than ideal for your multitenant system, but the code to send messages is arguably simpler and is a better match for the intended use case of per device keys. As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292330/azure-eventhub-multiple-partition-key-points-to-same-partition) you would need to do something rather dirty to get each publisher their own partition, and you would be outside the designed use cases.

Cross linking [questions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cf044cd-61d0-4fbc-8167-428342f05145/event-hub-device-authorization?forum=servbus) can be useful.

Comment: I am sorry about the typo, but i am still able to publish to other partitions even though i use SAS Token. It seems like a bug in the API.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete explanation on Event Hubs publisher policy refer [this blog](http://readtocode.blogspot.com/2015/02/event-hubs-publisher-policy-explained.html).

In short, If you want publisher policy - you will not get partitioned sender. Publisher policy is an extension to SAS security model, designed to support very high number of senders ( to a scale of million senders on event hub ).

Comment: when I am using SAS token, I must not be able to publish the events using CreatePartitionedSender, but when i try doing that, I do not get any exception and also the vent is published to some random partition Id. I was expecting an exception from the API instead. There is now a possibility that a rogue device can publish events to any partition even though it is authenticated using SAS Token.

Comment: Hi @Bussa.. Thanks a lot for your comment. I understood the problem. This is fixed now. You will not be able to create a Partitioned Sender on a Publisher specific sender any more.

Answer (score -1):

With its current authentication model, you can not grant so fine-grained access to publishers. Authentication per partition is not currently supported as per [Event Hubs Authentication and Security Model Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn789974.aspx).

You have to either "trust" your publishers, or think on different tenant scheme - i.e. Event Hub per tenant.

Comment: You sure about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292330/azure-eventhub-multiple-partition-key-points-to-same-partition and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn836025.aspx suggest otherwise. If CreatePartitionedSender bypasses publisher SAS restrictions, then it's a bug according to the documentation.

Comment: @cacsar, please help me, as I am having troubles understanding how exactly will you limit a SAS to only specific PartitionID? Again, if you have better answer and a working sample, you are free to post it here! And what will stop a publisher from publishing to another PartitionID? Not to mention, that the documentation you refer goes even further: `It is a best practice for publishers to be unaware of partitions within the Event Hub`

Comment: More over, again the same documentation, which you misread states `Service Bus provides SAS policies at the namespace and *Event Hubs level*.` Not `at Event Hub Prition Level`. And last but not least, again, same doc. mentions that `Partitions are a data organization mechanism and are more related to downstream parallelism than to Event Hub throughput. `

Comment: The problem is coming from API method CreatePartitionedSender, which will publish the event to the partitionId provided irrespective of the publisherID that was specified while authentication via SAS key. My only concern is to avoid any rogue device  from publishing into partition used by other tenant.

Comment: if you closely look at the documentation it suggest at several places that is not good idea to directly address partition from publisher anyway. So your design at first place conflicts with what Microsoft recommends as best practice for using Event Hubs. And yes, nothing can stop any publisher to publish to any partition. Because the authentication model covers an `Event Hub` not a `Event Hub Partition`.

Comment: The only other way to handle this problem is to use a different event-hub for each tenant which has the downside of not being able to scale the my system collective for all tenants. Also, I will have to generate a new policy for each event hub with send and listen permissions and my understanding is  that the policies are limited for a service bus namespace. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: or just to let all tenants send to same event hub and even same partitions. You are in control of the process anyway. And you are correct - there is limit on number of policies per namespace. But your question begins to get out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: You'll find in my answer that there is MS example code that binds the sends from a particular token to a particular partition. Receiving is another matter.