# Event Hub Partition Key Algorithm

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I need to programmatically find the partition for a given key in Event Hub.

Kafka the algorithm looks like this

```
Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2("54000024".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) % 16 == 9
```

In Event Hub the key is being written to partition 6.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Azure's EventData.PartitionKey decide which partition to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876671/how-does-azures-eventdata-partitionkey-decide-which-partition-to-write-to)

Comment: This is intentionally an implementation detail as it may be extended with other strategies and change over time.   There is no supported way to compute the partition for a given key external to the Event Hubs service.    The service uses a custom implementation of Jenkins' lookup3 extended with a weighting factor based on the number of partitions.